# Static resources pdf file open in a new tab

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce

I have one vf page pdf which is dynamic and there is another (staticTest_pdf) which i have stored in static resources. and my requirement is open both pdf after click on Action button (call Lighting component).

Dynamic pdf is open in new tab by action button which calls a lightning component, but i don't know how to open static resources pdf also in new tab.

my code is below

Lighning controller which redirected to new tab

```
({
    openNewWindow : function(component, event, helper) {
        var recordId= component.get('v.recordId');
        var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
        dismissActionPanel.fire();
        var objId=recordId.substring(0,3);
        console.log('object id'+objId);
        window.open('/apex/OrderConfirmation_EU_Export?id='+recordId,'_blank'); // it is working
        window.open('($resources.StaticTest_pdf)','_blank'); // not working
    }
})
```

Lighting component

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.openNewWindow}"/> 
</aura:component>
```

Comment: I tried the same but was unable to open a static resource however you can open two visualforce pages the second one containing the static resource as below:         
<apex:page >
<script>
    window.open('{!$Resource.pdfprevie}', '_parent');
 </script>   
</apex:page>

Comment: I already tried it but not working.